# How to get the current process list in windows

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to show all processes which are currently running on my system.
Can any one guide me to do that.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to know that :-) Why ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Actually this is one of the task of mine which i have to show to my boss and i have read the inno help document. I got little idea. But i cant move forward regarding this issue. can you help me

Comment: I can't think of any real usage for this, but well, boss is boss :-)

Comment: haha well said TLama.But Am very new to inno scripts i need to learn more info about inno

Comment: @TLama (I wish you were still here...): a usage would be to know if a service program (e.g. a VNC server) is already installed, when such programs (e.g. TightVNC) don't really leave a trace of their installation directory in the registry.

Comment: @Matthieu, well, for that one would not list all the processes rather than just checking whether the specific process is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use WMI for this task since WMI can list also 64-bit processes which I think the Windows API way cannot. Here is an example which uses the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class to query list of running processes:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  WM_SETREDRAW = $000B;
var
  ProcessList: TNewListBox;

// this is a substitution for missing BeginUpdate method
// of TStrings class
procedure WinControlBeginUpdate(Control: TWinControl);
begin
  SendMessage(Control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
end;

// this is a substitution for missing EndUpdate method
// of TStrings class
procedure WinControlEndUpdate(Control: TWinControl);
begin
  SendMessage(Control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
  Control.Refresh;
end;

function GetProcessNames(Items: TStrings): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  WQLQuery: string;
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemServices: Variant;
  WbemObject: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := 0;

  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');

  WQLQuery := 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process';

  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(WQLQuery);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    Items.Clear;
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      WbemObject := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
      if not VarIsNull(WbemObject) then
        Items.Add(WbemObject.Name);
    end;
    Result := Items.Count;
  end;
end;

procedure RefreshButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // this try..finally block is used to reduce annoying visual effects
  // when filling the list box; Inno Setup doesn't publish BeginUpdate,
  // EndUpdate method pair, hence this home brewn solution
  WinControlBeginUpdate(ProcessList);
  try
    GetProcessNames(ProcessList.Items);
  finally
    WinControlEndUpdate(ProcessList);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  RefreshBtn: TNewButton;
  ProcessPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  ProcessPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');

  ProcessList := TNewListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ProcessList.Parent := ProcessPage.Surface;
  ProcessList.SetBounds(0, 0, ProcessPage.SurfaceWidth,
    ProcessPage.SurfaceHeight - 33);

  RefreshBtn := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  RefreshBtn.Parent := ProcessPage.Surface;
  RefreshBtn.Left := 0;
  RefreshBtn.Top := ProcessPage.SurfaceHeight - RefreshBtn.Height;
  RefreshBtn.Caption := 'Refresh';
  RefreshBtn.OnClick := @RefreshButtonClick;
end;
```

Comment: That is really help full. may i know what does the following line represents " WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2'); "

Comment: It connects to the `root\CIMV2` WMI namespace on the `localhost` computer and if succeeds return the `SWbemServices` object. For more information see the [`ConnectServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720(v=vs.85).aspx) method reference.

Comment: yes i got it dude.But even if i changed it in to "users\safesquid" instead of "root\CIMV2" i got the  list of current running processes

Comment: That's not possible. The `Win32_Process` class is stored under the `root\CIMV2` namespace. You would get the *"Invalid namespace"* exception when you'd try to connect to a not existing namespace.

Comment: Here am working on win64 machine, i tried with different directories

Comment: yes i got that same error what you have said before ( invalid name space)

Comment: I have embedded this code in my installer, and on a rare occasion it cannot create  WbetScripting.SWbemLocator object, and shows a corresponding dialog box. I tried troubleshooting. All the necessary dlls were in their places and registered. So I haven't figured out why it failed.