# Waiting for a process to exist in "native" C++?

Tags: c++, process

Not really sure what other information to provide. I'm quite new and attempting to make a basic process checker for good practice/measure. Using native C++ (I think that is what Dev C++ uses? What is that C++ version called by the way?). Anyways, how do I make sure a process, say, string process = "crossfire.exe"; exists?

Comment: I think you'll have to resort to OS API

Comment: Well I cant use VC++ API, because I'm using Dev C++. Isn't there any way??

Comment: I don't develop on windows, so I'm not aware how to do it, but it might be an inclusion and a linkage to some sort of system library.

Answer (score 1):

This is an operating system function - nothing in the language will allow this directly.

On Windows see [How to get the current process list in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624431/how-to-get-the-current-process-list-in-windows/23630293#23630293)

On linux see [Linux API to list running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes)